# How can I access lodash in the javascript console when using reflux

Tags: javascript, require, lodash, refluxjs

I am working on an app which uses the Reflux framework around React. When we want to use an external library in a file we require with:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Then we can use the `_.` to access all the lodash methods. I would like to also like to be able to access `_.` in the javascript console when developing. Is there a way to require lodash so that it is available there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount it in `componentDidMount()` in some component. like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window._ = _;
}
```